# Logout exception flooding elmah

Tags: exception, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership, elmah

I am using ASP.NET membership, and in particular a copy of the membership code included in the MVC project. I am also using elmah to log exceptions. I am getting flooded with the following when people sign out.

```
System.Web.HttpException: Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.
```

Here is the stack trace sent

```
System.Web.HttpException: Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I cannot seem to find any reason for this. It is not causing an issue for end users, but would still like to resolve/learn about it.

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found and fixed the problem. I am using a UseSSL attribute, which redirects any action for the controller to switch to https. When I removed that it works fine, I really don't need SSL on sign out, so I applied the attribute to all other actions and not the controller and it stops the exception from occurring.